# Having trouble saving node input to a string

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodes, getter-setter

Below is a class I have for a 2 class project.  Basically I want to parse the title of the wiki page, and save it to the string title or something I can call from another class using something like `retrieveTitle.setText(WikiSearcherExtension.title);`  In eclipse its telling me the local variable title isnt being used at all to store the node information.

It wouldnt let me paste the xml as a block of code so here is the url I have been using http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=xml&rvprop=timestamp&rvlimit=1&rvtoken=rollback&titles=test&redirects=

```
public class WikiParserTrials {

    private String wikiInformation;
    private String wikiUrl;
    String title;

    public void urlRefactor(String url) throws IOException {
        String wikiPageName = url.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        wikiUrl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=xml&rvprop=timestamp&rvlimit=1&rvtoken=rollback&titles=test&redirects=";
        setUrlInformation();
    }

    private void setUrlInformation() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(wikiUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        wikiInformation = "";
        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            wikiInformation += line;
        }
    }

    public class ReadAndPrintXMLFile {

        public void main(String argv[]) {
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(wikiInformation));

                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("normalized");

                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

                    NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("to");
                    Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
                    String title = (getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

                }

            } 
            catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What eclipse is tellin you that title is no being used, which is true, you need to store it in a property of the class. Note that you are re-declaring title locally. So the property title never gets it value.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `String` before `title` inside the main method. You are overwriting the global one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its never used is as luiso1979 said. You are overriding the String.

```
String title;
String title = (getCharacterDataFromElement(line`));
```

what you should have is

```
String title = "";
title = (getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute `title` is a `String` and in your `for` sentence you override the value (you should fix as other solutions said), so you only get the title of the last node. I suggest you to use another data structure like `List<String> titles = = new ArrayList<String>();` and store all the values `titles.add(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));`